# Using cophyloplot in R to plot mirror-image trees with as many horizontal links as possible

Tags: r

I am using `cophyloplot` in the `ape` package in `R` to make two phylogenetic trees face-to-face with links (the trees are rooted at tip 1).

```
library(ape)
set.seed(1)
tree1 <-read.nexus("tree1.nex", tree.names = NULL)
tree2 <-read.nexus("tree2.nex", tree.names = NULL)
tree1$tip.label<-(1:28)
tree2$tip.label<-(1:28)
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28)
b <- c(1,15,3,4,6,5,23,26,28,27,16,14,22,18,19,10,9,8,7,11,25,24,2,21,12,13,17,20) 
association <- cbind(a, b)
cophyloplot(tree1, tree2, assoc = association, length.line = 4, space = 30, gap = 3,col="red", show.tip.label=FALSE)
```

If I rotate some of the nodes, however, one tree can be manipulated so that more links appear horizontal/straight (i.e. the trees are more mirrored).

Is there a way to automatically plot the trees with links so that they are, by default, the best fit/mirror image to/of each other? i.e. get as many links as possible to be horizontal?

EDIT: Is there also a statistical measure of how alike the trees are? Or is that given by `dist.topo(tree1, tree2, method = "PH85")` ?

Comment: What is in `tree1.nex` and `tree2.nex`?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor in this example, tree1.nex is a virus tree and tree2.nex is a host tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "best fit" can be directly visualized with the R package *phytools*.

Use the `cophylo()` function (wich does the same as *ape*'s `cophyloplot()`) and set rotate to TRUE.

```
obj <- cophylo(tree1, tree2, assoc = association, rotate = T)
plot(obj)
```